# Scroll Pagination working only with Older Version of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm Using this ScrollPagination Plugin in my Page and it works fine with older versions of jQuery (version 1.8.3) but when I add new jQuery, it doesn't works. Can't find out whats deprecated in this Plugin. I'm new with jQuery, Thanks in advance!!

```
    (function($) {

    $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {

        var settings = { 
            nop     : 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
            offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
            error   : 'No More Feeds!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                        // displayed. You can change this if you want.
            delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                           // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
            scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                           // but will still load if the user clicks.
        }

        // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        // For each so that we keep chainability.
        return this.each(function() {       

            // Some variables 
            $this = $(this);
            $settings = settings;
            var offset = $settings.offset;
            var busy = false; // Checks if the scroll action is happening 
                              // so we don't run it multiple times

            // Custom messages based on settings
            if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = 'Click for More';
            else $initmessage = 'Click for more';

            // Append custom messages and extra UI
            $this.append('<div class="content"></div><div class="loading-bar">'+$initmessage+'</div>');

            function getData() {

                // Post data to ajax.php
                $.post('ajax.php', {

                    action        : 'scrollpagination',
                    number        : $settings.nop,
                    offset        : offset,

                }, function(data) {

                    // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);

                    // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
                    if(data == "") { 
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);   
                    }
                    else {

                        // Offset increases
                        offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

                        // Append the data to the content div
                        $this.find('.content').append(data);

                        // No longer busy!  
                        busy = false;
                    }   

                });

            }   

            getData(); // Run function initially

            // If scrolling is enabled
            if($settings.scroll == true) {
                // .. and the user is scrolling
                $(window).scroll(function() {

                    // Check the user is at the bottom of the element
                    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height() && !busy) {

                        // Now we are working, so busy is true
                        busy = true;

                        // Tell the user we're loading posts
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html('Loading Feeds');

                        // Run the function to fetch the data inside a delay
                        // This is useful if you have content in a footer you
                        // want the user to see.
                        setTimeout(function() {

                            getData();

                        }, $settings.delay);

                    }   
                });
            }

            // Also content can be loaded by clicking the loading bar/
            $this.find('.loading-bar').click(function() {

                if(busy == false) {
                    busy = true;
                    getData();
                }

            });

        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There's really no surprise that JQuery plugins are only compatible with certain versions of JQuery, especially since JQuery changed a lot when going to version 2.x. Have you tried to see if there is a newer version of the plugin available? I doubt anyone here will go through the entire source code looking for deprecated functionality without even knowing what versions are used or what error is thrown. Even then, this question is too broad to be likely to get any answers.

Comment: sorry, I've edited my question, it works fine with jQuery v1.8.3

Comment: Which version you are using now that doesn't work? Have you tried using jQuery Migrate (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)

Comment: i'm using jQuery v2.1.1 and how its used, I don't want to include old codes and jQuery, how can I make this code running with new version 2.x